# Safety in Warsaw Poland

Tags: safety, poland, female-travellers

Just want to be prepared, with no intention of judging or whatsoever, I have some questions about safety in Warsaw:

1. Is it safe to stay in a dorm? I've read some reviews where the person get robbed when asleep, some strangers came in and searched jeans for keys and open the locker, look for cash and valuables.
2. What time during the day is it safe for a female to walk alone?

Answer (score 16):

I've stayed in Warsaw for a week as a tourist last year and slept in many dorms in central/eastern Europe.

1. Is it safe to stay in a dorm?
   First of all: check the reviews of the dorm you've selected (there are many websites to do that). It'll give you an idea of the "risk" encountered. Security may vary a lot depending on the location of the building.

Warsaw is as safe as other European capitals. But I suggest you take several precautions so that you're not robbed of your valuables :

- Do not leave your belongings without surveillance
- Use locks

For instance: before going to bed put all your belongings in your backpack. Lock it up, tie your bag up to the bed, hide it under the bed. Keep the key with you. This will protect you against thieves who are most of the time looking for easy targets.

2. What time during the day is it safe for a female to walk alone?
   For sure, no problems in the city center during the day.

Comment: For this question it would be helpful to know whether you are female as security can be and be perceived quite differently by the sexes.

Answer (score 13):

### Sleeping in dorms / hostels

Relating dorms specifically in Warsaw I can't answer but I have stayed in all kind of dorms and never had any trouble. Of course you hear stories and strange things really happen. I remember a guy once, in the next room, whose belongings were stolen. This was classified as a safe hostel by the reviews.

In the end it's up to you and your practices. You are in a shared space with unknown people. You should either carry or secure your most valuable belongings (ID, Passports, etc. included). In principle no one is going to steal a bag of dirty laundry but if you walk around showing your latest iWhatever, etc. someone might actually think it's worth it to break or take your bag/lock. In general the more valuable things you leave unattended/show off the biggest is the risk. Mitigation is up to you.

**Side note about hostels:** Locks are not always safe. Some are very easy to break. In some hostels you are allowed to leave your most valued goods at the reception.

### Security in Warsaw

I was there this year. It's a perfectly normal city. It felt very safe even at night. At least around the center where I spent most of the time. I was staying in the suburbs and even during the commute in public transport, by night, it seemed fine.
Again, common sense is the most important thing here. Don't put yourself in strange places / situations and you should be safe.

Comment: For this question it would be helpful to know whether you are female as security can be and be perceived quite differently by the sexes.

Answer (score 6):

I live in Warsaw whole my life.

I can't answer on question 1 because I've never slept in dorm in Warsaw :)

With regard to question 2 I think it's safe city but it's worth to be watchful as there are pickpockets. At night you can see many drunk people who can behave loud, sometimes you can see some street fight but I was never afraid someone could beat me.

I had one unpleasant situation at night, when some man forced me to give him my phone, telling that he has a knive. Given that I live here 28 years I think one bad situation is not much but I try to have my eyes at the back of my head, mainly at night.